# Compare schema visual studio 2015 how to create separate files for indexes and statistics

Tags: visual-studio-2015, database-schema

I'm comparing database schema in visual studio 2015. It add indexes and statistics in create table file, but i want to have separate files for indexes, statistics and all keys. In vs2010 it used to create separate files but i'm not sure if I'm missing any settings in vs2015. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Here's answer for that so what happened after vs 2010 everything added under project\dbo\tables instead of project\schema objects\schemas\dbo\tables\indexes. The new definitions are not split into different files and folders rather it keeps everything in the same file, which makes the file system path less deep and reading all information related to a specific table is easier.

So now I will have to upgrade my database projects to support new file structure. It won't support the old file structure anymore.